# Insert time/date into database when somebody lands on page

Tags: php, mysql

How would one go about inserting an entry ('time/date', in this case) into the database if a user lands on a particular page. That is, automatically.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: Let the database compute the date by using something like [CURDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)on your insert statement. Typically leads to more consistent dates, consistent tz, etc, esp if you have multiple web servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See MySQL [Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Example:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table SET column = NOW()");
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Ended up doing this based on these replies: "UPDATE `---` SET `---`= NOW() WHERE `---`='---' "

Comment: I'm glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$date =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

// mysql insert query here to insert $date.
?>
```

Add this script to the top of your page.